Obtaining Correct Redirections Before Triggering Listeners in Puppeteer on Node.js
Currently, I'm learning Node.js with the Puppeteer library for scraping. I have a question regarding redirections. I encountered a scenario like this: I want to scrape the URL 'https://www.facebook.com/ladbible', but Facebook redirects to the correct URL 'https://www.facebook.com/LADbible'.
Upon checking the network tab in the browser's inspect tool, the initial load on Facebook returns a status 302, and then Facebook automatically redirects to the correct URL. I've attached an image for reference.

Here is how my code looks:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const testRun = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome' });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const link = 'https://www.facebook.com/ladbible/'
 
    page.on("requestfinished", async (request) => {
        const response = request.response();

        if (response.url().includes(link) && response.status() == 200) {
            console.log(response.url());
        }
    });
 
    await page.goto(link, { waitUntil: "networkidle2", timeout: 0 });
};

testRun();

Since I want to set up the listener for scraping, is it possible to obtain the final redirection and then trigger the listener to get the response?"

page.goto() returns the final response so you most likely do not need to listen for requestfinished

Yes, however, I must incorporate the listener function to fetch the URL response. This response contains elements and scripts that I require for scraping. Unfortunately, it fails because the URL I set is incorrect, leading Facebook to automatically redirect to the correct URL. Consequently, I am unable to retrieve the response from the final redirect by Facebook.

What data you do you want to scrape? There may be a more direct way than you assume. Does the data you want arrive immediately after the redirect without interaction or does it require interaction first? Never use timeout: 0.

Are you asking how to get the html for that response? It's in response.text()

@ggorlen I want to retrieve the data html response from the final redirection. The current issue is: how can we set the listener to identify the final redirection URL?

@ferdinand There are a lot of ways, and it depends on how much you need the code to generalize. networkidle0 sort of works, but isn't fast or reliable (if the destination page keeps long running requests open, it can hang forever if you're using timeout: 0). Better to wait for a selector on the final page, or if all the pages you're manipulating use the same URL scheme, wait for the lowercased version of the page. Other approaches are possible, but they're all use case-dependent. Regardless page.on("requestfinished" is probably not needed. Use waitForResponse or the return val of goto.

You do not need to use the listener to get the final navigation response. Puppeteer listens for responses by default and returns the final response as the result to page.goto():
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
const result = await page.goto('https://www.facebook.com/ladbible/');

console.log('final', result.url()); // 'https://www.facebook.com/LADbible'
console.log('redirects', result.request().redirectChain().length); // 1

await browser.close();

If you still want to use the listener, for whatever reason, you can do something like this:
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

let navRequest;
page.on("requestfinished", async (request) => {
    if (request.isNavigationRequest()) {
        navRequest = request;
    }
});

await page.goto('https://www.facebook.com/ladbible/');

console.log('final', navRequest.response().url()); 'https://www.facebook.com/LADbible'
console.log('redirects', navRequest.redirectChain().length); // 1

await browser.close();


Why timeout: 0? If something goes wrong, this will spin forever. Better to give up after 3 minutes at the most and log the error so the maintainer can fix the problem, or at least catch the error and re-attempt the operation.

I have only modified the code provided by OP in the parts that are relevant for the question P.S. streamlines the examples a little bit
